# Using data attributes and jQuery how can I select elements by data attribute name AND data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to select elements by data attribute name AND data attribute value.

Something like (but obviously, it doesn't work)

```
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    var y = $('.my-class').attr('data-id', i); //trying to select here
    y.html('input' + i);                                
}
```

Have no idea how to achieve this, please help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
var y = $('.my-class[data-id="' + i + '"]');
```

since the selector `.my-class` is repeated, you can cache it

```
var els = $('.my-class');
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    var y = els.filter('[data-id="' + i + '"]'); //trying to select here
    y.html('input' + i);                                
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/as7wB/)